# Range for ngram in R

Tags: r, text-mining

Using a command like the following in r it is possible to give the level of ngram you expect to executed:

```
myDfm <- dfm(txt, ngrams = 2, ignoredFeatures = stopwords("english"))
```

Is it possible to give a range for ngram like from (1,3)?

Example code in python:

```
vectorizer = TfidVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words, use_idf=True, ngram=range(1, 3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myDfm <- dfm(txt, ngrams = c(1,3), ignoredFeatures = stopwords("english"))
```